# Modify login validation functionality in Magento

Tags: validation, magento, authentication

I have multi-store Magento set-up. Could anyone let me know from where i can modify the (customer)login validation function in Magento. 
I have multi-store setup with not shared customer account. I do need to omit validate store-id when validate the login.

I assume customer account controller handle much functions as redirection, etc. /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
But, not sure in which file the login($login['username'], $login['password']); function has been implemented.

Comment: Did you check loginPostAction() method in that controller? Actually, that login method is in this file Customer/Model/Session.php

Comment: @Alex, this is something like what i was looking for. Yes i checked loginPostAction() already. As i need to work with storeId i better try in Customer/Model/Session.php file. Thx. Hope it will work for me.